# The font "Kozuka" can somehow not be used in XeLaTeX on my system

Tags: fonts, xetex, cjk

This seems very weird to me, because the Kozuka fonts are the only ones that cannot be used.

My system: Windows 8 64-bit, MikTeX 2.9 64-bit, TeXWorks 0.4.4 r.1003.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Meiryo}

\begin{document}

Hello, world! わたしはにんげんです。

\end{document}
```

works and produces the expected output: Text containing Latin and Japanese characters.

Using `\setmainfont{Arial}` instead of `\setmainfont{Meiryo}` also produces the expected output: Latin characters and squares instead of Japanese characters because Arial doesn't contain those characters.

Using `\setmainfont{alkjsfd}` also produces the expected output: fontspec error: "font-not-found".

But using `\setmainfont{Kozuka Gothic Pro R}` produces just an empty sheet of paper.

I have no idea why.

Comment: Oh, and it does not make any difference if I use
    \usepackage{xeCJK}
    \setCJKmainfont{Kozuka Gothic Pro R}

Comment: Is it possible that there is some weird kind of copy protection in the Kozuka fonts since it's stemming from Adobe? Do those fonts work on your system?

Comment: I don’t own the font with the issue, but with Fonts “Microsoft JhenHei“, “Microsoft YaHei” and “Arial Unicode MS” (note that there are also spaces in the names) your example runs fine.

Comment: This is really a shot in the dark: [Security update for Windows lets fonts disappear](http://www.h-online.com/news/item/Security-update-for-Windows-lets-fonts-disappear-1771419.html).

Comment: That was it, Speravir! I can't believe it! The fonts disappear under certain applications even though they are actually there. If I open the PDF in SumatraPDF, they're visible!

Comment: Oh. My. God!!! Let’s hope for a fast fix!

Comment: @Speravir If you want to add your comment as an answer I can accept it because that was the reason after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really a shot into the dark, but recently Microsoft made a security patch, that now may show some unexpected effects with TrueType, OpenType and also Type1 fonts, see [The H Security: Security update for Windows lets fonts disappear](http://www.h-online.com/news/item/Security-update-for-Windows-lets-fonts-disappear-1771419.html).

**Update:**
If this really was the cause for the issue, then now the font should re-appear:
[The H Security: Microsoft brings back the fonts](http://www.h-online.com/security/news/item/Microsoft-brings-back-the-fonts-1773744.html).

Answer (score 2):

I have no problem with all of these fonts:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Meiryo}
%\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{KozGoPro-ExtraLight}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{KozGoPro-Regular}
%\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{STKaiti}

\begin{document}

Hello, world! わたしはにんげんです。

\end{document}
```

Current TL 2012 with `xelatex`

Comment: Same. I think it's a good idea to always use the font's postscript name rather than the full name (i.e., "KozGoPro-Regular" vs. "Kozuka Gothic Pro R").

Comment: After having tried your code, Kozuka does still not work on my system. I didn't have the STKaiti font, so I downloaded it and it just works. Maybe I should download another version of Kozuka.

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason I found that all the versions of Kozuka don't work under my system, that is KozGoStd, KozGoPro, and KozGoPr6N. However, converting the fonts to the TrueType format using FontForge did the trick. (One must flatten the CID first, unless you want to generate 14 font files for numbers, kana, etc. `->CID->Flatten`)